# Why is `summary_col` ignoring the `info_dict` parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex, linear-regression, statsmodels

I need to run some linear regressions and output `Latex` code with `statsmodels` in `Python`. I am using the `summary_col` function to achieve that. However, there is either a bug or a misunderstanding from my side. Please see the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.iolib.summary2 import summary_col

np.random.seed(123)

nsample = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
X = np.column_stack((x, x ** 2))
beta = np.array([1, 0.1, 10])
e = np.random.normal(size=nsample)

X = sm.add_constant(X)
y1 = np.dot(X, beta) + e
y2 = np.dot(X, beta) + 2 * e

model1 = sm.OLS(y1, X).fit()
model2 = sm.OLS(y2, X).fit()
```

Now, to have a table with the two models side by side:

```
out_table = summary_col(
    [model1, model2],
    stars=True, 
    float_format='%.2f',
    info_dict={
        'N':lambda x: "{0:d}".format(int(x.nobs)),
        'R2':lambda x: "{:.2f}".format(x.rsquared)
    }
)
```

Hence I'd expect a table providing the number of observations and the $R^2$ *only* since I am explicit about the `info_dict` argument. The result I get however is the following:

```
==============================
                 y I     y II 
------------------------------
const          0.81**  0.63   
               (0.34)  (0.67) 
x1             0.22    0.35   
               (0.16)  (0.31) 
x2             9.99*** 9.98***
               (0.02)  (0.03) 
R-squared      1.00    1.00   
R-squared Adj. 1.00    1.00   
N              100     100    
R2             1.00    1.00   
==============================
Standard errors in
parentheses.
* p<.1, ** p<.05, ***p<.01
```

Please notice how there are two extra rows with the normal r-squared and the adjusted one. My desired behavior would be:

```
==============================
                 y I     y II 
------------------------------
const          0.81**  0.63   
               (0.34)  (0.67) 
x1             0.22    0.35   
               (0.16)  (0.31) 
x2             9.99*** 9.98***
               (0.02)  (0.03) 
N              100     100    
R2             1.00    1.00   
==============================
Standard errors in
parentheses.
* p<.1, ** p<.05, ***p<.01
```

The documentation is not the best yet: https://tedboy.github.io/statsmodels_doc/generated/statsmodels.iolib.summary2.summary_col.html

Any ideas on how to displayu only the information asked by the `info_dict` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at the source code at

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/iolib/summary2.py

We can see that the function `summary_col` takes `info_dict` as an argument and uses it in the following way

```
if info_dict:
    cols = [_col_info(x, info_dict.get(x.model.__class__.__name__, info_dict)) 
        for x in results]
```

In this case, it means that then is called `_col_info(model1, info_dict)` and `_col_info(model2, info_dict)` in order to generate your `N` and `R2` rows. The absence of `mypy` and comments makes these functions quite obscure actually.

Later on, the `cols` list will be added to the variable `summ` that will be part of a `Summary` object.

```
smry = Summary()
smry._merge_latex = True
smry.add_df(summ, header=True, align='l')
```

However, `cols` is actually a redefinition, it was defined before as

```
cols = [_col_params(x, stars=stars, float_format=float_format) for x in results]
```

and that constituted the first part of `summ`.

The issue is that `_col_params` will add `R-squared` and `R-squared Adj.` whether you like it or not, here is the source code

```
rsquared = getattr(result, 'rsquared', np.nan)
rsquared_adj = getattr(result, 'rsquared_adj', np.nan)
r2 = pd.Series({('R-squared', ""): rsquared,
                ('R-squared Adj.', ""): rsquared_adj})

if r2.notnull().any():
    r2 = r2.apply(lambda x: float_format % x)
    res = pd.concat([res, r2], axis=0)
res = pd.DataFrame(res)
res.columns = [str(result.model.endog_names)]
return res
```

So what I would suggest is to manually modify the `tables` attribute of your output

```
rm_extra_rows = lambda t :  t.iloc[list(range(6)) + [8,9],:]
out_table.tables = [rm_extra_rows(el) for el in out_table.tables]
```

After that I get

```
In [53]: out_table
Out[53]: 
<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary2.Summary'>
"""

=====================
        y I     y II 
---------------------
const 0.81**  0.63   
      (0.34)  (0.67) 
x1    0.22    0.35   
      (0.16)  (0.31) 
x2    9.99*** 9.98***
      (0.02)  (0.03) 
N     100     100    
R2    1.00    1.00   
=====================
Standard errors in
parentheses.
* p<.1, ** p<.05,
***p<.01
"""
```

which should be what you wanted to get.

Comment: you could submit a pull request to add the option not to add R2-squared and adj, given that you already went through all this code.

Comment: @Josef, thank you for the advice. I have tried, let me know if I did anything wrong
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/8658

Comment: Thanks to @ThePunisher there will be an `include_r2=False` option in the next statsmodels release (0.14)

Comment: @Josef, thank you for guiding me through this. I hope to contribute more in the future.